# VBA function for multiple Ifs for multiple outcomes

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm very new to the VBA functions/anything above basic user level computers.  I'm trying to create a function in excel that returns a value (there are five values that the ratings can equate to) based on its rating in six different areas(or cells).  Trying to auto populate the rating of a company based on the 6 different criteria.

Example If G34 > 84.99%, J34 >79.99%, K34 ="Yes" Then "T" but If G34 < 84.99%, J34 >79.99%, and K34 ="No" Then "T-".   I've been trying an ElseIf statement but keep running into issues.  Help is very appreciated!!!

Below is the very elementary full function that I'm trying to get:

```
IF(G34>84.99%, J34>79.99%, K34="Yes", M34 >89.99%, N34 = 100%, O34>89.99%, Then "T", 
IF(G34>74.99%, G34<84.99%, J34>79.99%, K34 = "Yes", M34 >79.99%, M34 <89.99%, N34 = 100%, O34 <89.99%, O34>79.99%, Then "T-", 
IF(G34>64.99%, G34<74.99%, J34<79.99%, G34 > 74.99%, K34 = "NO", M34 >64.99%, M34 <79.99%, N34 = 100%, O34 <89.99%, O34>79.99%, Then "P", 
IF(G34>59.99%, G34<64.99%, J34<74.99%, J34 > 59.99%, K34 = "NO", M34 >49.99%, M34 <64.99%, N34 < 100%, O34 < 79.99%, Then "P-", 
IF(G34<59.99%, J34<59.99%, K34 = "NO", M34 <49.99%, N34 < 100%, O34 < 79.99%, Then "U")))))
```

Comment: Without fully parsing that formula (so I'm not totally sure) I suspect you'd be better off with a lookup table for some of the logic.  VLookup has a "fuzzy match" feature where one enters the fourth parameter as True and you get a "band" match instead of an exact match.

Comment: some computer science might help here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ijOIueCJkI

Answer (score 3):

Brief comments instead of a full rewrite

In VBA

- Use **and** between your if terms
- VBA doesn't recognize a % in the number so compare to the actual value in the cell
- You don't assign your results to anything just saying "T" doesn't do anything

> ```
> IF G34>0.8499 and J34>0.7999 and K34="Yes" and M34 >0.8999 and N34 = 100 and O34>.8999 Then 
>   variable = "T" 
> elseif ...
>   variable = "T-"
> elseif ...
>   variable = "P"
> else
>   variable = "no case"
> end if
> ```